# How to understand this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a C# novice. Can someone help me understanding this C# lambda expression?

```
var projs = allCustomers.SelectMany(osd => osd.phoneNumbers,
                                   (osd, osv) => new { customer= osd, phoneNumber= osv });
```

Thanks/Hem

Comment: there are two lambda expressions in there, both of them pretty trivial; which one is giving you problems?

Comment: In fact both. This is first time I see two lambda expressions. As I understand, the first one returns all phone numbers for all customers as list. I do not understand the OSV in second lambda expression. Is the first one passed as input to second one?

Comment: IF you have trouble understanding lambdas, pick a simpler example first. Such as Select or Where.

Comment: The lamdbas are much simpler than you think: its only their combination that is complex. `osd => osd.PhoneNumbers` does exactly what it says: reutrns the `PhoneNumbers` property of an `osd` (e.h. whatever type `allCustomers` contains. To know how the lambda's are related you would need to read the `SelectMany`  documentationm as @Selman22's answer explains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.100).ASPx) of `SelectMany`.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(
      this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
      Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector,
      Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

There are three parameters:

```
source :
Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>
A sequence of values to project.

collectionSelector
Type: System.Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>>
A transform function to apply to each element of the input sequence.

resultSelector
Type: System.Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult>
A transform function to apply to each element of the intermediate sequence.
```

In your case, `source` is the `allCustomers`, `collectionSelector` is the expression:

```
osd => osd.phoneNumber
```

and the `resultSelector` is:

```
(osd, osv) => new { customer= osd, phoneNumber= osv }
```

Here the first expression says take each `customer` and return it's `phoneNumbers`.In the second expression, the type of `osd` is `customer`, `osv` is `phoneNumber` and the result is an anonymous type.It takes each customer and the phone number and creates an anonymous type using these values.

Here is an example of what this query does:

```
Customer - Phone Numbers
------------------------
John      1234567,2331212,1122334
Jack      1456771,9485323
Juliet    2401232
```

The result would be:

```
John   1234567
John   2331212
John   1122334
Jack   1456771
Jack   9485323
Juliet 2401232
```